# Find a way to increment formula in merged cells and blank cells

Tags: google-sheets

It's my first time posting here, I tried to look for something similar to what i am looking for but couldn't find anything, but if I just didn't look enough, I apologize.

My problem is as follows:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10yx-WO_SlOnFLNW83N8wucOrcexfLtt1TE2FDzTAQbc/edit#gid=799857548

I have a data table with information I receive from somebody. I then need to use that information to feel kind of individual product data table on another sheets, and add more to it.

Instead of copy everything of sheets one in sheets 2, I would like it to feel by itself.

I tried with `=Cellsadress` or `=OFFSET` and other stuff but couldn't manage to get what I want.

When i put every formula in the green table on sheets 2 and try to increment it by dragging down, the formula values increase by 25 approximately. but i want it to increase by only one, or find another way to show the information in the column of sheets 1 to reflect in different cell of sheets 2.

In my real document i have 100 of lines, so i cant do it manually like i could do with 4 lines.

Is there a way to do that?
If somebody have a solutions i would be gratefull

Answer (score 1):

try this formula for `C32` `=INDIRECT("'Sheets 1'!F"&(int(row()/25)+2))`

when you copy-paste this formula into cell `C57` or `C82`, it will take values from `'Sheets 1'!F4` and `'Sheets 1'!F5`, respectively

[image]

Comment: Wow, it look like it works, i will make it for every cell i need to fill and see how it goes, thank very much for your precious time and your answer !

Comment: Its working ! thank you so much , have a very nice day Sergey :)

Comment: @LouisBonjean No problem, I'm glad my answer was helpful to you.